# Which HTTP request should I use while using updateOrCreate() method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, httprequest, lumen

I'm using updateOrCreate but should I use `Post Http Request or Put request` while I'm using it?

Comment: You could use either. Laravel by default uses puts for an update and post for a create.

Comment: I know that I can use any .. but what is proper ?

Comment: In supplement of my answer: I can recommend you Adam Wathan conference talk about organizing the controllers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI It's not a direct answer to your post but it help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @cbaconnier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We doesn't know your architecture so it's difficult to give you an appropriate answer.

But, speaking in general termes, A CRUD use the methods as follow:

- **GET** index()
- **GET** create()
- **POST** store()
- **GET** edit($id)
- **PATCH** update($id)
- **DELETE** destroy($id)

In your scenario, I assume you doesn't know the ID of your resource.
In that case it can't be a **PATCH** (or PUT). The left over would be **POST**.